# Downloading a File Via Angular $.http POST

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am trying to download a zipped file that my server generates in my UI.  I am at a loss as to how to get the file to download though.  We have it setup so that we can download with window.open where we pass the url and it opens a blank page.  We need to do a POST where it has a body now.  I havent seen a way to send that along with a window.open.  Does anyone have any pointers on how i can get access to the returned file?

Here is my current code...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/archives/download", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getArchive(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody List<GeneratedReport> reportList) {
    System.out.println(reportList.get(0).getFileLocation());
    List<String> filesToDownload = new ArrayList<>();
    reportList.stream().forEach(e -> filesToDownload.add(e.getFileLocation()));
    filesToDownloadAndZip(response, filesToDownload, "zipped_file.zip");
    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=zipped_file.zip");
    return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(200, HttpStatus.OK);

}

private void filesToDownloadAndZip(HttpServletResponse response, List<String> filesToDownload, String archiveFileName) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = FileIO.CreateArchive(filesToDownload);

        if (baos != null && baos.size() > 0) {
            // Set the content type and attachment header.
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + archiveFileName);
            response.setContentType("application/zip");
            response.setContentLength(baos.size());
            baos.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
        } else {
            LOG.debug("File was null or size 0, try again");
        }
    } catch(Exception ex)
    {
        LOG.debug(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The js i have is.....

```
$http.post('api/archives/download', $scope.downloadItems)
                .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                    //I dont know what to do here..... :(

                })
```

Comment: I think it can be easy if you return the data to a new window. In your controller, return a HttpResponseMessage with the file data content. In js, you can do something like this: window.open('api/archives/download' + yourSerializedData, '_blank');

Comment: @RicardoPontual thats what we have been doing but we can no longer add the "data" in the url.  we need to have it sent in the body of the request.